kafkajs doesnt connect a broker that inside a pod
I'm trying to run kafka pn kubernetes pod, and than using kafkajs (in nodejs) as an event bus.
but the kafka isnt connect into the broker.
The problem is when im trying to connect to a broker, i tried connect "kafka-srv:9092" and to "kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local:9092", but im still receiving the error of
D kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local","retryCount":2,"retryTime":1374}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-06-01T15:18:02.594Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local","broker":"kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local:9092","clientId":"ticketing","stack":"Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26)"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-06-01T15:18:02.595Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Connection error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local","retryCount":3,"retryTime":2242}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-06-01T15:18:04.915Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local","broker":"kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local:9092","clientId":"ticketing","stack":"Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26)"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-06-01T15:18:04.916Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Connection error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local","retryCount":4,"retryTime":5076}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-06-01T15:18:10.054Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local","broker":"kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local:9092","clientId":"ticketing","stack":"Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26)"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-06-01T15:18:10.055Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Connection error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local","retryCount":5,"retryTime":11724}
Error starting the consumer: KafkaJSNonRetriableError
  Caused by: KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local
    at Socket.onError (C:\Users\almog\Downloads\programming\programming\microservices\ticketing\kafka\node_modules\kafkajs\src\network\connection.js:210:23)
    ... 3 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  name: 'KafkaJSNumberOfRetriesExceeded',
  retriable: false,
  helpUrl: undefined,
  retryCount: 5,
  retryTime: 11724,
  [cause]: KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local
      at Socket.onError (C:\Users\almog\Downloads\programming\programming\microservices\ticketing\kafka\node_modules\kafkajs\src\network\connection.js:210:23)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    retriable: true,
    helpUrl: undefined,
    broker: 'kafka-srv.default.svc.cluster.local:9092',
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    [cause]: undefined
  }
}

kafka-depl.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka
          image: bitnami/kafka:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1Gi"
              cpu: "500m"
            limits:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "1"
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://:9092
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://kafka-srv:9092
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zookeeper-srv:2181
            - name: ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER
              value: "yes"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://:9092
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://kafka-srv:9092
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zookeeper-srv:2181
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka
  ports:
    - name: kafka
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zookeeper
          image: bitnami/zookeeper:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "1Gi"
              cpu: "500m"
          env:
            - name: ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN
              value: "yes"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
  ports:
    - name: zookeeper
      protocol: TCP
      port: 2181
      targetPort: 2181


consumer.ts
import { Kafka } from "kafkajs";
import { TicketCreatedConsumer } from "./events/ticket-created-consumer";

console.clear();

const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: "ticketing",
  brokers: ["kafka-srv:9092"],
});

const run = async () => {
  const ticketCreatedConsumer = new TicketCreatedConsumer(kafka);
  await ticketCreatedConsumer.consume();

  const closeKafka = async () => {
    await ticketCreatedConsumer.close();
    process.exit();
  };

  process.on("SIGINT", closeKafka);
  process.on("SIGTERM", closeKafka);

  console.log("Consumer connected to Kafka");
};

run().catch((err) => {
  console.error("Error starting the consumer:", err);
});



Both of them are in the same namespace which is named "default"?

yes, both of them in default

Ok. it seems to be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792143/kafka-failing-to-connect-broker-on-docker


I'd recommend Strimzi or Helm over manual services. 2) Try seeing if DNS resolves in other ways https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

